# Use Android XML Layouts in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am integrating MoPub ads into my app, and need to add the following Android XML Code "to your Activity’s or Fragment’s layout" (from https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/banner/)

```
<com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
android:id="@+id/adview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
```

How would I go about doing this in a Flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26301), you can't do that right now, hopefully a package will be available later.